# DateTime parameter in Ajax

Tags: ajax, datetime

I'm creating a wcf service that I test by Ajax.
I have a method which has parameter object whose one of the properties is DateTime.

In Ajax, here is how I define that object:

```
var newObject = { "date": "12-12-2011 9:01:26 PM", "name" : "something" }
```

But the method doesn't get executed.

I tried with 12/12/2011. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, something like this:

```
var newObject = { date: "/Date(" + eventDate.getTime() + eventDate.getTimezoneOffset() + ")/", "name" : "something" };
```

Hope it helps